# What do those black image corners mean?

Tags: lens, raw, sensor

I've downloaded a sample RAW image from the brand new **compact superzoom** camera Sony DSC-RX10 Mark IV and opened in [RAW Therapee 5.2](http://rawtherapee.com/).
As the camera is very new, the program doesn't know how to handle it and the result looks like this:

[image: DSC RX10M4 from RAW]

What do those black corners mean? Is the wide end of the lens (focal length: 8.8mm, 35mm equivalent: 24.0mm), f/5.6 unable cover the sensor and the corners need to be restored/computed from remaining pixels? It's not just a vignetting, is it?

I thought this would happen only if you attach a DX lens to an FX body etc.
Do all compact cameras with zoom lenses behave like this?

Note 1: I've found how to correct it with a lens distortion slider in RAW Therapee manually.
Note 2: It doesn't happen with RAWs taken with longer focal distances.

Sample image taken from this [DPReview gallery](https://www.dpreview.com/samples/3529337823/sony-cyber-shot-dsc-rx10-iv-samples-gallery) (image 29/33). Direct file links don't work.

Comment: Which size does RT report? Is it the same size as in the camera spec? Or is it a bit more in each dimension?

Comment: Camera JPEG: 5472x3648, size in RT: 5488x3664. Slightly bigger but not enough to cause a vignetting like this.

Comment: I have the same problem on my a6000 with sel18200LE.but black corners appears just on 18mm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, most likely the lens doesn't cover the whole sensor at the wide end - but correcting for barrel distortion (which happens automatically when shooting JPEG) moves the vignetted corners outside the corrected image area. It's a trick employed to shave just a tiny bit more off the size of the lens.

Comment: so you are saying, Sony ships camera that has such noticeable vignetting before distortion correction is applied?

Comment: @aaaaaa Apparently so.

Comment: @aaaaaa Definitely so. It just happens that I'm working on a lensfun correction profile for the RX10 MkIII right now, and it exhibits the same behavior (it sounds like the Mk IV uses the same lens... I hope!). I've seen this at the wide end of other fixed-lens cameras, even some wide primes. Manufacturers take maximum advantage of the lens being a known quantity.